# How to access a <div> from the HTML embedded by <object>

Tags: javascript, object, html, siblings

I have a webpage that has several `<div>` sections ("navcol" and "maincol"). The "navcol" div contains `<object data="mypage.html">`.  Inside mypage.html there are buttons the user can click to select pages to be inserted into "maincol". I need to gain access to the innerHTML of "maincol" in the main page with Javascript, so I can do the insertion (like using an iframe). Can someone put me on the right track?

PS. I am using `<object>`, because I want to have HTML 4.0 "Strict" and Iframes are not in "Strict", but s are.

Answer (score 0):

From within the page in the object element, you can get access to the upper–most browsing context using:

```
window.top.document
```

so you can try:

```
window.top.document.getElementById('maincol');
```

no doubt only within limitations imposed by the same–origin policy though.

e.g.

```
<div id="mailcol">maincol</div>
<div id="navcol">
  <object data="foo.html"></object>
</div>
```

in foo.html:

```
<button onclick="
  alert(window.top.document.getElementById('mailcol').innerHTML)
">button</button>
```